# cant set feature (marker/icon) from forEachTileCoord coords, openlayers

Tags: maps, openlayers, coords, xyz

new to openlayers, i am currently trying to grab all tiles at certain zoom level within the view extent and add a feature/icon to each tile location, i can grab tile coords using

```
src.getSource().getTileGrid().forEachTileCoord
```

problem is it returns Z,X,Y tile coords (ie [16, 31689, 20858]) and i cant find anyway to either set icons location with these coords or convert them to lon/lat (eg 'EPSG:4326'[-5.928909184411161, 54.5921176536682]

iv tried

```
ol.proj.toLonLat
```

but it returns 0.00014373044545912343, 0.284665959233962, 20858.

as im new i may have something fundamentally wrong with my setup, or im completely missing something,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get actual coordinates you can use `getTileCoordExtent` / `getCenter`. This will get you the center coordinates for each tile.
By default the coordinate format is `EPSG:3857` and no conversion should be needed to add a Feature.

```js
const zDirection = 0;
const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
    zDirection: zDirection,
  })
});

const style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 70,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .2)'}),
  }),
});
const layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  style: style,
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 5000000],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
  layers: [tileLayer, layer],
});

map.on('moveend', function () {
  const view = map.getView();
  const tileGrid = tileLayer.getSource().getTileGrid();
  const extent = view.calculateExtent();
  const zoom = tileGrid.getZForResolution(view.getResolution(), zDirection);
  const features = [];
  tileGrid.forEachTileCoord(extent, zoom, function (tileCoord) {
    const center = ol.extent.getCenter(tileGrid.getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord));
    features.push(new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(center)));
  });
  layer.setSource(new ol.source.Vector({features: features}));
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#map {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers@v6.14.1/src/ol/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: perfect, now i see exactly what im missing, thank you